# How install Crawlera via setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, setuptools, scrapyd

I want to install crawlera avec setuptools in docker.

in my scrapy.cfg file i have:

```
[deploy=test]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = Crawling
```

i test by `scrapyd-deploy -l`  and i have

```
test              http://localhost:6800/
```

in my `setup.py` i have 
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
setup(
    name         = 'Crawling',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = Crawling.settings']},
    install_requires=['scrapy-crawlera'],
)
```

at the end in my `requires.txt`  i have `scrapy-crawlera`
but crawlera **is not** installed in my docker.

Comment: Why not use `pip install -r requires.txt` in DockerFile?

Comment: yes you are right  but I want to know why i can't install it via setuptools

Comment: So you saw your scripts as a package that need to be installed? have you used `python setup.py install`?

Comment: @Zealseeker it work's, i had a problem in my Docker.

Comment: So you'd better delete the post or answer by yourself it make it sense for other readers.

Comment: @Zealseeker Yes Thanks

Comment: @parik To make it perfect, you could accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker was not installed correctly, i resolve my problem by re-installation Docker